# Testing legacy ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, unit-testing, selenium

I need help figuring out how to test old legacy asp.net web forms.

A lot of web pages in our project are written long time ago and now it is getting to a point where maintaining/adding extra features are a pain in the neck. There are no methods whatsoever. The codes are not modularized and server side code are all over the place at the front pages (.aspx) mixing together with the UI logic.

Rewriting these legacy asp.net web forms seems to be the only way to go for long-term benefits. However, here is our problem. These pages all work fine right now, but no one on our team completely understands the business logic behind them and reading through the code line by line will be very painful. We thought maybe writing some test cases and apply that same test on our newly re-factored, modern web forms and compare the results will be more promising and accurate.

Does anyone know how i can go about this? How to test legacy asp.net web forms if the codes are not organized and madularized? Any suggestion or recommendation will be helpful.

So far i have looked at Selenium but seems like this is more for UI testing than for business logic. My main focus will be what data gets pulled from the database and displayed on the form and what data gets written into database (especially which tables) after the submit.

Also looked at Visual Studio built in Test suite, but seems like this approach requires the code to be organized in methods and functions so I didn't continue my reading.

Another thought i have in mind is monitoring the database and see which tables get changed during the period when i manually open a web page and input/submit some data. Will this be a good option?

Any thought will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might be of some help http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/155488/91155

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but I think you're going to have to go through the pain of extracting the business logic at some time.  You already have an unmaintable, unmanageable system which is surely a business risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These pages all work fine right now, but no one on our team completely understands the business logic behind them and reading through the code line by line will be very painful.

- Ok, so this is really the crux of your problem. Do you have access to the stakeholders of this application (i.e whoever it was designed for?) They are probably the best people to explain to you how its supposed to work. You need to get access to these folks and have them give you at least a crash-course in the "domain" of the application.
- Only when you and your colleagues fully understand how this system works can you test it. If you don't have access to the stakeholders, then don't panic - just take this thing one module at a time and start mapping it out.
- You don't have to go all out and learn the whole thing up-front - take it one module or subsystem at a time, make plenty of diagrams about how the various parts of the *business domain* work from the perspective of the users, and do the same then for how they *currently* work. Put both diagrams side by side and start planning how you might refactor the code to be organised more like the business flow, and less like the existing flow.
- This can be a tricky process for sure but actually once you get going, especially once you know how the system should ideally flow based on the previous point, it's not that bad - bear in mind that you will surely be able to copy/paste a lot of your existing code - in fact, you should probably *avoid* the temptation to try to fix bugs on the fly at this stage. Focus instead on the organisation of your classes, etc, so as to make then adhere to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) - any classes that broadly stick to this will typically be very testable.
- Any bugs or really poorly written code can be flagged at this stage for fixing later on; a key point here is *reaorganise* not re-write!
- Armed with that knowledge, the next step is to write a test specification for the various parts of the application, based on the new design of the modules. That means, lots of tests and test methods (using whatever framework you like, MSTest or xUnit, etc). You really can't avoid this but remember, one module at a time!
- As DanielMann pointed out, it might be worth looking at something like [Specflow](http://www.specflow.org/) that will let you write test specifications in a natural(ish) language form - you may even be able to get he stakeholders on board to help write the tests!
- You don't have to have literally every detail specified at first; once you have identified the major "business units" in terms of logic, you can break them down into smaller and smaller chunks of conceptual behaviour

So you may end up with tests like (just an example)

```
LoginModule_WhenPasswordIsWrong_RedirectswithErrorMessage()
{
   //write some code in here that exercises the LoginModule and assert that it behaves as expected
   //The really important thing is to write these tests based on the NEW design
   //and NOT the existing system.
   Assert.Fail("Write the test!");
}
```

Now, the key thing here - most, if not all of these tests, will not even *compile* and even the few that do, will probably *fail*. That's actually a good thing! Because now you have a clear path of what you have to do - which is to make those tests pass by implementing the new design. Best to do this in a branch of the original!

So in the example above, you might not even have a clearly defined login "module" - the code might be scattered across several pages and classes. But by writing your "ideal" tests up-front, based on an ideal design, you now have a target to aim for. And also you don't have to be totally purist about it - there is no sin in bending the rules and making some tests less granular than the ideal case - you can come back and do that later.

- Rinse and repeat - every system you do, is one less to do tomorrow!
- Once your initial set of test methods is passing, you can then "zoom in" and start refining them, in the process fixing bugs and crappy code (the same thing, in many respects :) you came across earlier.

Best of luck with it!

Comment: For writing proper tests of the business logic, it may be worth investing in learning SpecFlow or something similar. They can write their test cases in non-programmer-friendly language, and have the business users validate the tests. I've had great success taking that approach when trying to modernize and test a very complicated legacy system.

Comment: @DanielMann yes that is a really good point - I'll update the answer to mention this